# Регулярное выражение. Поиск длины поля имейла

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть регулярное выражение для почтового адреса, в котором мне нужно добавить проверки длин: 1 - часть до собачки, 2 - часть после собачки, 3 - общая длина всего поля. Я пытался использовать вперед смотрящего, но, к сожалению, ничего не вышло. Одно особое условие - регулярное выражение должно оставаться таким, как оно есть, нужно лишь добавить нужные проверки на длину. Выражение выглядит так:

```
^((\"[^\"]+\")|([\w\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\}\{\-\|\'\/\?\)\(\u0400-\u04FF\~\=\`]+\.)*([\w\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\}\{\-\|\'\/\?\)\(\u0400-\u04FF\~\=\`])+)@(([0-9A-Za-z\u0400-\u04FF][\-\_]{0,1})+(\.))+(([0-9A-Za-z\u0400-\u04FF][\-\_]{0,1})+?)$
```

Comment: Но зачем? Зачем проверять почтовый адрес? Зачем проверять его некорректным выражением, в конце концов?

Comment: А какой язык программирования нужен?

Comment: @Yuri, заэкранировал точки?

Comment: Проверять почтовые адреса, особенно самостоятельно — плохая идея

Comment: @andreymal, особенно на длину.

Comment: даже если бы это выражение правильно проверяло корректность email я бы его таким как есть не оставлял. его же читать невозможно из за обратных косых, которые внутри квадратных скобок не нужны (кроме случая квадратной скобки и тире не в начале/конце)

Comment: @vp_arth К сожалению понимая всю сложность ситуации, я вынужден все-таки ее написать. Поскольку мне поставили конкретную задачу

Comment: @Yuri javascript

Comment: @andreymal Я понимаю, но у меня нет выбора. Мне поставили конкретную задачу, и мне нельзя ее даже поменять, нужно лишь расширить ее проверками на длину

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается такое регулярным выражением на проверку email:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*)$/
```

И поиском нужных значений с помощью `match`:

```js
function length(val) {
  var value = val.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*)$/);

  console.log('До собачки: '+value[1].length+'\nПосле собачки: '+value[2].length+'\nВесь размер: '+value[0].length)
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email">
<button onclick="length(document.getElementById('email').value)">Проверить</button>
```

Вот вариант с вашим регулярным выражением, но оно не корректное:

```js
function length(val) {
  var value = val.match(/^((\"[^\"]+\")|([\w\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\}\{\-\|\'\/\?\)\(\u0400-\u04FF\~\=\`]+\.)*([\w\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\}\{\-\|\'\/\?\)\(\u0400-\u04FF\~\=\`])+)@(([0-9A-Za-z\u0400-\u04FF][\-\_]{0,1})+(\.))+(([0-9A-Za-z\u0400-\u04FF][\-\_]{0,1})+?)$/);

  var all = value[0].length,
      part_one = value[1].length,
      part_two = value[5].length + value[8].length
  console.log('До собачки: '+part_one+'\nПосле собачки: '+part_two+'\nВесь размер: '+all)
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email">
<button onclick="length(document.getElementById('email').value)">Проверить</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @messiah, если мой ответ правильный, то отметьте его